# len(kf) + object of type 'generator' has no len()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

While I wrote the kfold codes to  validate, I cannot use the object for len() as object, and I've ever tried list() but failed again. BTW, the processing time became very slow and spent over 4 hours but the memories still less than 20%, would anyone can help me to solve these problems:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from scipy import interp

def plot_roc(X, y, clf_class, **kwargs):
    kf = KFold(len(y),n_splits=3,shuffle=True)
    y_prob = np.zeros((len(y),2))
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train = y[train_index]
    mean_tpr = 0.0
    mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
    all_tpr = []
    for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X,y)):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train = y[train_index]
        clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        # Predict probabilities, not classes
        y_prob[test_index] = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
        fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y[test_index], y_prob[test_index, 1])
        mean_tpr += interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr)
        mean_tpr[0] = 0.0
        roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
        plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, label='ROC fold %d (area = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))
    mean_tpr /= len(kf.split(X,y))
    mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
    mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
    plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, 'k--',label='Mean ROC (area = %0.2f)' % mean_auc, lw=2)
    
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], '--', color=(0.6, 0.6, 0.6), label='Random')
    plt.xlim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.ylim([-0.05, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Receiver operating characteristic')
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    plt.show()
      

print ("Support vector machines:")
print(plot_roc(X,y,SVC,probability=True))

print ("Random forests:")
print(plot_roc(X,y,RF,n_estimators=18))

print ("K-nearest-neighbors:")
print(plot_roc(X,y,KNN))

print ("Gradient Boosting Classifier:")
print(plot_roc(X,y,GBC))
```

and the error message is as follows, even I've tried to use list() to enclose the kf (use split substitute for kf):

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11212/2950209521.py in <module>
     39 
     40 print ("Support vector machines:")
---> 41 print(plot_roc(X,y,SVC,probability=True))
     42 
     43 print ("Random forests:")

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11212/2950209521.py in plot_roc(X, y, clf_class, **kwargs)
     23         roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
     24         plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, label='ROC fold %d (area = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))
---> 25     mean_tpr /= len(kf.split(X,y))   
     26     mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
     27     mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

And if I changed the len(kf) as  len(list(kf.split(X,y))), the plot became very strange as attached.
[image]

Comment: This line `len(kf.split(X,y))` is failing because it is asking for the number of elements in `kf.split(X,y)` as if it were a list. But it is a generator, not a list. This `len(list(kf.split(X,y)))` will make that error go away, but your program may fail if generating all the elements and putting them into a list results in a list that is too big to handle.